# Error when trying to use a library built with Rollup that export types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollup

I am facing an error in my rollup build, and I can't figure out what is happening.
This is my configuration.

```js
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';

import packageJson from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true,
      rollupCommonJSResolveHack: false,
      clean: true,
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
      tsconfigOverride: {
        exclude: ['**/*.stories.*', '**/*.test.*'],
      },
    }),
    svgr({ icon: true }),
    postcss({
      extract: false,
      modules: true,
      use: ['sass'],
    }),
    dts(),
  ],
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
};
```

It seems to build normally without errors, but when I publish the package and try to use it in another project, I get the following error message:

[image: Error when trying to use the library]

The error comes from my generated file, `index.esm.js`.
I export several types from this library; it feels like they should be in ts file or something like that. Is this an error in the way the builder is configured?

[image: File with error]